# How to convert IQueryable to DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, linq

I wrote the query using LinQ and I used the `CopyToDataTable` method. At that line it is showing implicit conversion type error from my database type to `System.Data.DataRow`.

```
var query = from i in dbContext.Personaldetails
            where i.ID == 1
            select i;

            return query.CopyToDataTable();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CopyToDataTable` requires collection of `DataRow` objects. See How to: [Implement CopyToDataTable Where the Generic Type T Is Not a DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx) to solve this problem.

UPDATE: If your entity has nullable field, you can modify `ObjectShredder.ExtendTable` method. Find place where new columns are added to table, and remove second parameter, which provides type of data in column (DataColumn class does not support nullable data types):

```
foreach (PropertyInfo p in type.GetProperties())
{
    if (!_ordinalMap.ContainsKey(p.Name))
    {
        DataColumn dc = table.Columns.Contains(p.Name) ? table.Columns[p.Name]
            // do not provide column type
            : table.Columns.Add(p.Name); 

        _ordinalMap.Add(p.Name, dc.Ordinal);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented that logic but at the query.copytodatatable it is showing error that can't implicit conversion type.

Comment: @nanicharan make sure you use `CustomLINQtoDataSetMethods`, not those from LINQ to dataset.

Comment: I used the same method.i'll send my code.can u please check it once.

Comment: @nanicharan I created tables recently with exactly same code. Just copy-paste it from msdn. And make sure you use `CustomLINQtoDataSetMethods` extension. E.g. you can call it directly `CustomLINQtoDataSetMethods.CopyToDataTable(query)`

Comment: var query = from i in dbContext.Personaldetails
                        where i.ID == 1
                        select i;
            DataTable table = query.CopyToDataTable(); I used in this way.I wrote this query inside a method.next to that method i declared CustomLINQtoDataSetMethods

Comment: thanks,                                                            i changed the code.the error rectified.now i want to load the data into my dhtmlx grid.

Comment: ,error rectified at that statement but,in the  CustomLINQtoDataSetMethods, i declared two                            public static DataTable CopyToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
            {
                return new ObjectShredder<T>().Shred(source, null, null);
            } here it is showing "Extension method must defined in a top level static class"

Comment: Seems like you declared `CustomLINQtoDataSetMethods` class inside some other class. Move it to the top level, directly in some namespace.

Comment: hi,
 I used copy to datatable method to convert the linq query to datatable and when i debug the application,it is throwing "NotsupportedException handled by user code" and "dataset doesnot support system.data.nullable" at the second foreach loop in Datatable Extendable method().

Comment: Also you can verify if property type is nullable `type.IsGenericType && (type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))` and provide nullable parameter type instead `p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]`